# Full-width image with aspect ratio in React Native

Tags: image, reactjs, user-interface, react-native, layout

I want to `require()` a static image in a Home screen component I've written, and I want that image to be the full width of the display (which here happens to also be the full width of the container) while maintaining the aspect ratio.

Here is what I have so far. The Home component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    StatusBar,
} from "react-native";

import Container from "../components/Container/Container";
import Header from "../components/Header/Header";
import FullWidthImage from "../components/Images/FullWidthImage";

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <FullWidthImage source={require("./lifting.jpg")}/>
                <Header/>
                <StatusBar translucent={false}/>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

And the FullWidthImage component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import Proptypes from "prop-types";

export default class FullWidthImage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Image source={this.props.source} style={style.image} resizeMode="contain"/>
        );
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        width: "100%",
        borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 2,
    }
});
```

I've been trying for a while and looking around on SO for a good answer but I can't find one (for an example some of them assume you have an uri and are not using `require()`). Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you hoping to have the image as a background? Or just fixed at the top of the screen?

Comment: Both actually, I want to to be full width at the top of the screen behind the <Header />

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.5

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

1. I created the following component

   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";

   import Proptypes from "prop-types";

   export default class FullWidthImage extends Component {
       static propTypes = {
           requireSource: Proptypes.number // is actually a require(some-url)
       };

   ```
   render() {
       let image = this.props.requireSource;
       const { width, height } = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
       const ratio = height / width;
       const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

       return (
           <Image source={image} style={{width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_WIDTH*ratio}} resizeMode="contain"/>
       );
   }
   ```

   }
2. And then I use it in my Home component like this:

This way I can have the image I want to show in a component in the same folder as that component.

Note: The formatting of this answer seems messed up, don't know how to fix it, I tried `ctrl+k` on the code snippets.

Comment: How its work with a uri:'web_direction'?? I tried using image={uri:'web_direction'} but don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the not so well documented library **resolveAssetSource**.

Like this:

```
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View, 
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
var resolveAssetSource = require('resolveAssetSource');
var imgSrc = resolveAssetSource(require('./200x150.png'));
console.log(imgSrc.width, imgSrc.height);
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const IMAGE_RATIO = imgSrc.height/imgSrc.width; 
...
<Image source={imgSrc}  
style={{width:SCREEN_WIDTH, height:SCREEN_WIDTH*IMAGE_RATIO}}/>
...
```

The important being:  `var imgSrc = resolveAssetSource(require('./200x150.png'));`

I used this issue to get the answer, and then I went and try it ; )
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4025

Comment: I had a look at this too, but `require()` works from the "viewpoint" of the file where it is called, and I want to organize my project so that I have the FullWidthImage component in my components folder, and use it from my Home component where I also have the image in the same folder, to make it clear where it is used. If I have the `require()` in FullWidthImage then I can't do <FullWidthImage source="./lifting.jpg"/> from the Home component since the uri will be used relative to the FullWidthImage component location, not relative to the Home component location. See what I mean?

Answer (score -4):

Use resizeMode (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#style)

```
resizeMode: "cover"
```

In your code:

```
...

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        width: "100%",
        borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 2,
        resizeMode: "cover"
    },
    container: {flex:1}
});
```

Or try with other types:  contain, cover, stretch, center, repeat.

Comment: That is litterally what I am already doing in the code I posted in my question... It does not set the height of the image proportionally.

Comment: Ok, I admit I underestimate the question. But I went and solve it for you. My stupid pride : d
Go ahed and give it a try if you already haven't, and give feedback

Comment: You are doing the exact thing I am in the code I posted, what do you mean "go ahead and give it a try"?...